# How to query Kibana data through REST API

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have access to someone's Kibana dashboard. I want a programmatic way of accessing the data there from one of the panels. Is there a way to do this ?
eg: Is there is a REST API access to query for data with parameters like time range.

Comment: did you check Kibana documentation ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/api.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the data used in the panel by going to

1. that particular visualization and
2. go to Inspect
3. click request and copy

This request can be used in a curl command or in a rest call to get the data you saw in the panel
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Kibana page by entering the appropriate URL and port, such as:

```
192.241.122.33:5601
```

On the left hand side, in the top corner, select the wavy line square, scroll down, and select

```
Dev Tools
```

Once you are in the query console, execute a query. The simplest one would be to just select everything from a particular table, such as:

```
POST /_sql?format=json
{
    "query": "SELECT * FROM users"
}
```

Comment: thanks. is this designed to be accessible from outside that Kibana machine ? eg: Can it be  accessed from a different machine via curl.

Comment: @EnnioMorricone yes, its very much possible, ultimately kibana dashboard is backed by elasticsearch index and that's where data reside, kibana is just a visualisation tool and in ELK stack, Elasticsearch is the heart(that's where data is stored). please refer my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the backing elasticsearch index of Kibana dashboard, then you can query the data in same way you query the data from elasticsearch. Kibana is just a visualisation tool and Its data is backed by elasticsearch, Please refer [ELK stack](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elk-stack) for more info.

Elasticsearch provides all the search and index functionality in [form of REST endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rest-apis.html) and, you can easily build your search query against the elasticsearch index and get the data you want pragmatically.